# how to increase ranges in loop with vba?

Tags: vba, imacros

```
Sub Worksheet_Change()

Set Target = ActiveCell
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

[A1:F20].Copy
[H4].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

[A22:F42].Copy
[H24].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

[A44:F64].Copy
[H46].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

[A66:F86].Copy
[H68].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

[A88:F108].Copy
[H90].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

[A110:F130].Copy
[H112].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

[A132:F152].Copy
[H134].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

[A154:F174].Copy
[H156].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

[A176:F196].Copy
[H178].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

[A198:F218].Copy[H200].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Target.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Please format your code by indenting it four spaces; it will show in your post as code rather than as part of the text. Also, your question refers to a loop, but I don't see any loop in the code?

Comment: I want to apply loop where I have written copy and pasteSpecial repeatedly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try this:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

[A1:F20].Copy
[H4].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

With [A22:F42]
    For i = 1 To 9
        .Offset((i - 1) * 22).Copy
        [H24].Offset((i - 1) * 22).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: But What to do for n number of tables?

Comment: You are welcome. Then you may want to mark asnwer as accepted. Thank you! If you want to do that at every worksheet change, then you can put that code in the `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` event handler in `ThisWorkbook` code pane. Of course you must reference all ranges to the `Sh` worksheet object which you can easily do by 1) wrapping all the code in a `With Sh .... End With` block and 2) adding a dot (`.`) before _every_ opening bracket (`[`) .